# firebase error while deploying my functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to upload a function now forever
this is the code inside my Indes.js file

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.onQuoteAdded = functions.firestore.document('Manager/Quote').onCreate((snap, context) =>{
const values = snap.data();
console.log(snap.data());

//send email

db.collection('loggin').add({ description: 'Email sent'});

});
```

I always get this in the terminal but it never gives me an uotput that the function was deployed.
Here is a picture of what the terminal outputs. [This is my screen afer trying to deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEE4u.png)

Does anyone know why it is not uploading the function.

Cloud it because I have my files placed wrong. I went ahead and dropped in the picture above my whole screen

this is what the firebase website looks likewhen i click on functions [Firebase website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgpwa.png)

Comment: Have you tried to connect with the function to see if it's working?

Comment: whenever I go into the firebase website inside the functions tab, it is saying still waiting for you first deploy @enzo

Comment: i have also tried to connect to it as well but it is not working